# Right shift of a node in a tree

Tags: tikz-trees

I want to shift a node to the right because it coincides with another node:

[image: no description]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=2.5cm, level distance=2.5cm]
\node {S}
  child {[dotted]  node {\{E.v:=0\}}}
  child {  node {E}
  child{[dotted]  node {\{T.v:=1\}}}
  child {  node {T}
  child {  node {F}
  child {  node {NB}}
  child{[dotted]  node {\{F.v:=SR(NB)\}}}}
  child{[dotted]  node {\{T.v:=T.v*F.r\}}}
  child [sibling distance=2cm]{  node {R2}
  child  {  node {$\varepsilon$}}}}
  child{[dotted]  node {\{E.v:=E.v+T.v\}}}
  child {  node {R1}
  child[sibling distance=0.8cm]{[dotted]  node {\{T.v:=1\}}}
  child [sibling distance=0.5cm]{  node {+}}
  child {  node {T}
  child {  node {F}
  child {  node {NB}}
  child{[dotted]  node {\{F.v:=SR(NB)\}}}}}
  child{[dotted]  node {\{E.v:=E.v+T.v\}}}
  child {  node {R1}
  child {  node {$\varepsilon$}}} }}
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably better to define the `sibling distance`s consistently for each level. I used `\tikzset` in the following code, but you can also set the level styles as options to the `tikzpicture` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=2.5cm]

% Setting sibling distance for each level of the tree
\tikzset{
  level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
  level 2/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm},
  level 3/.style={sibling distance=1.8cm},
}

\node {S}
  child {[dotted]  node {\{E.v:=0\}}}
  child {  node {E}
  child{[dotted]  node {\{T.v:=1\}}}
  child {  node {T}
  child {  node {F}
  child {  node {NB}}
  child{[dotted]  node {\{F.v:=SR(NB)\}}}}
  child{[dotted]  node {\{T.v:=T.v*F.r\}}}
  child {  node {R2}
  child  {  node {$\varepsilon$}}}}
  child{[dotted]  node {\{E.v:=E.v+T.v\}}}
  child {  node {R1}
  child {[dotted]  node {\{T.v:=1\}}}
  child {  node {+}}
  child {  node {T}
  child {  node {F}
  child {  node {NB}}
  child{[dotted]  node {\{F.v:=SR(NB)\}}}}}
  child{[dotted]  node {\{E.v:=E.v+T.v\}}}
  child {  node {R1}
  child {  node {$\varepsilon$}}} }}
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you,but I have another problem(see the initial tree)

Comment: @user29570: Updated the answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: thank you very much .How can I change the color of interrupted lines?to red

Comment: @user29570: after the `node{...}`, add `edge from parent[red]`